# Patterns for a jQuery or CSS pop-up menu from a button

Tags: jquery, css, menu, popup

I'm trying to figure out the best patterns for making a jQuery-based or CSS-based pop-up menu when clicking a button.

I'd like to have something like this:

[image]

I'm not even sure how to conceptualize going about this, so any help would be appreciated. Make it high-level if you want, though a working example (JSFiddle) would be best.

Thanks!

Comment: There are lots of plugins available for this. Do you want to create it from the scratch?

Comment: Not necessarily. Would you mind pointing me to a few of the better plugins?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Comment: @drachenstern I answered my own question (lengthily) and accepted it. Vote it up if you'd like so it rises to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually fairly easy to figure out, and much thanks is owed to @NateL in #jquery on IRC for helping me figure out the CSS on this.

Here's what I implemented:

### CSS

```
.all-checkboxes-menu
{
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  top: 28px;
  left: 7px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #999;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #999;
}

.tasks-submenu
{
  padding: 5px;
}

.tasks-submenu li
{
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.tasks-submenu li:hover
{
  background-color: #fcf7bd;
}
```

### HTML

```
        <div class="all-checkboxes-menu">
          <ul class="tasks-submenu">
            <li>All</li>
            <li>None</li>
            <li>Due Today</li>
            <li>Overdue</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

The crucial portion of the CSS is the `position: absolute`, and the parent div must be explicitly given `position: relative`. Note that `display: none` is used initially. In the jQuery code, I call `.css({'display': 'block'})` to show the submenu.

The result looks like this:

[image: Submenu]

Comment: Hmm, this works great in Firefox (and maybe others) but not IE; there is no drop-shadow and the menu is hard to see...

Answer (score 0):

We implemented that menu at the following location

http://www.allposters.com/ and even www.art.com , as it is javascript code you can copy the code from one of the javascriptfiles.

Its header_menu.js.

If you want to achieve without jquery or javascript , let me know we can implement with CSS also which is SEO friendly.

BUt to have good effects its better to implement through jquery or javascript , Let me know if you need any help i can provide you all the details.

Comment: @josh ,see this link which i got from google , they have lot of examples http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/ , start writing the code and if you get stuck update here.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/DropDown/DropDown.aspx

See if that dropdown works like you want it to. I'm not asking you to use that particular one, I'm asking if that's an effect you like.

A searchable term is "sharepoint dropdownlist" because sharepoint uses this same method to produce themeable dropdowns.